# Getting InvalidOperationException after conversion from .NET 2 to .NET 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.0

I upgraded my .NET 2.0 web application from .NET 3.0. It now compiles but when I try to login I am getting error "InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'ApplicationUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context". Obviously the call to database cannot be done but I can't see what my error is.

I got this in Startup.cs (ConfigureServices)

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


   services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Here is my ApplicationDBContext.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

The error stack reads like this:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet.get_EntityType()
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet.CheckState()
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet.get_EntityQueryable()
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync(MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable source,
>   Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync(MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable source,
>   LambdaExpression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable
>   source, Expression> predicate, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore.FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(string
>   userName)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(string
>   userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
>   ImSmart.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginViewModel model,
>   string returnUrl) in AccountController.cs
>   +
>                   var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: true);
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[]
>   arguments)

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the answer was to go back to `IdentityUser` instead of `ApplicationUser`.
That meant I also had to change everywhere in code where I used `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>` and `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` to `SignInManager<IdentityUser>` and `UserManager<IdentityUser>`.

After these changes, login works fine.